# SQL Server - find all rows where MyCol does not have 3x '(' e.g. MyCol = '(1(2(3' is fine but find '(1(23'

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to find all rows where MyCol does not have 3 instances of '(' in.
e.g. do not return the row where MyCol is '(101(2255(3355'
but do return the row where MyCol is '(101(2255' or '(101(2255|3355' because it does not have 3 ( in MyCol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (myCol VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @t VALUES 
('(101(2255(3355'),
('(101(2255'),
('(101(2255|3355')

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
WHERE   myCol NOT LIKE '%(%(%(%'
```